# How can i put youtube api inside vue3 project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to put youtube api in my vue project but i get this error, can someone help?
I did read topics about this but i cant make it

```
// append youtube iFrame API from https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api
// docs: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

import { store } from "../stores/stores";

export default {
    name: "YoutubeTV",

    data: function () {
    return {
      player: null,
      jukebox: false
    };
  },

  methods: {
    initYoutube() {
      const _ = this;
      console.log("initYoutube");
      this.player = new YT.Player("jukebox-player", {
        height: '236',
        width: '408',
        videoId: store.getters.getYoutubeTv.video_id,
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
      });
    },
    onPlayerReady(event) {
      console.log("Player ready");
      event.target.playVideo();
    },
    onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      console.log("Player state changed", event);
    }
  }
}

window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => {
  console.log("onYouTubeIframeAPIReady")
  initYoutube()
};
```

This is what i get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj75Z.png

Comment: It means what it says, initYoutube is a method on vue instance and you're trying to use it like a global, without "this". Check on how methods are used. It's a mistake to have side effects in component module (var tag, etc). The whole thing should probably be inside mounted() hook

Comment: Oh yea now it is working but i have some questions for check it is right or not. I put `this.initYoutube` to mounted and moved var tag etcs. to index.html it is right?

Comment: Preferably to mounted() too, unless this results in problems with multiple mounts. onYouTubeIframeAPIReady shouldn't have a chance to be triggered too early

Comment: You did solve my issue, thanks a lot sir.